# ASUS P5GC-MX support of RAM

Tags: memory, motherboard

Im a noob when it comes to hardware of the computer and im trying to figure out if this mothers supports 2GB of memoery on the slot or in total.

This is what's said about it on the official website:
2 x DIMM, Max. 2 GB, DDR2 533/400 Non-ECC,Un-buffered Memory 
Dual Channel memory architecture
* Refer to www.asus.com or user manual for Memory QVL (Qualify Vendor List)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Max memory supported is 2GB. Also [Intel page](http://ark.intel.com/products/34505/Intel-82945GC-Graphics-and-Memory-Controller) seems to support of Max of 2GB based on the Motherboard Chipset. Not 2GB each, but 2GB Total for the whole Motherboard.